# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not RowProxy

Tags: python, list

I make query like this in a function:

```
def get_artist_data(...):
    sql = 'select * from artist where id in (' + ','.join(map(str, artist_ids)) + ')'
    db_value = db.session.execute(sql).fetchall()
```

This is how `db_value` looks like:

```
[(121", u'', 55, u'John Lennon', datetime.date(1940, 9, 9),...), (123, u'', 23, u'Paul McCartney', datetime.date(1942, 6, 17),...)]
```

I want to loop through `db_value`:

```
for i in db_value:
    yield {"artist_id": db_value[i][0],
           "artist_name": db_value[i][3]}
```

This is what I get:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not RowProxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
for i in range(0,len(db_value)-1,1):
    yield {"artist_id": db_value[i][0],
       "artist_name": db_value[i][3]}
```

Comment: This can be close. It returns me no value if loops 1 times, but returns me a single value if 2 times. Can't figure out to return all.

Comment: I made it `for i in range(0, len(db_value)):` and it worked. Thanks!